# I received a 500 error after taking a survey for a question

Tags: support, bug, error-message

I noticed a new thing this morning about taking a survey for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373701/php-html-form-gets-placed-at-wrong-position) on Stack Overflow.

After finishing it, I received the following error:

> This page isn’t working stackoverflow.com is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

Are they aware of this? I had to hit the "reload" button  on that page for it to reload properly.

Comment: There are some stability issues currently: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402034/what-is-wrong-with-mso-homepage

Comment: The error isn't specific to the survey or one we show for exception inside the web app, so something probably failed somewhere else on the stack.  I just wanted to mention that nothing important happens _after_ you leave SurveyMonkey, just redirects, event logging, and a thank you message.  If you got to that point, your responses will have been successfully recorded.

Comment: @BrianNickel I couldn't give specifics. When I clicked on the "done" button or something like that, there was a surveymonkey URL in my browser and the error message in my browser screen, that was all. Well, besides the "reload" button below that that I had to click in order to get redirected to the question I took the survey from.